# Trying to manipulate class info after input from the user

Tags: javascript, string, class, object, input

I'm basically trying to learn how to take user input and display the input based off of the class information I already have set up. In other words, I want the user's input to become part of the string that is generated from the class information. I currently get the string in the browser, but I get "null" instead of the user input when I hit the button. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
class Vehicle{
//Set up object
  constructor(color, direction, currentSpeed, topSpeed, engineStarted){
    this._color = color;
    this._direction = direction;
    this._currentSpeed = currentSpeed;
    this._topSpeed = topSpeed;
    this._engineStarted = true;
  }
      
  accelerate(){
    return `Car is now travelling @ ${this._currentSpeed} mph.`;
  }
}

let input = document.getElementById('input1');
let myCar2 = new Vehicle("Green", 233, input, 90);
function whatsTheSpeed() {
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML +=  myCar2.accelerate();
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <button onclick="whatsTheSpeed()">Speed</button>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `input.value` instead of just `input`

```
let input = document.getElementById('input1').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` variable selects the `<input>` element. But since you are getting the value `null` as result it probably means that your script is executed before the HTML you are trying to select. Make sure that you first have your HTML elements and at the bottom of the page your `<script>` tag with this script in it.

Then when the `document.getElementById('input1');` does give you an element use the `value` property of that element to get the current `value` in the input.

If you want your car to update the speed every time you click then you need to update your instance in the `whatsTheSpeed` function.

```js
class Vehicle{
//Set up object
  constructor(color, direction, currentSpeed, topSpeed, engineStarted){
    this._color = color;
    this._direction = direction;
    this._currentSpeed = currentSpeed;
    this._topSpeed = topSpeed;
    this._engineStarted = true;
  }

  setSpeed(speed) {
    this._currentSpeed = speed;
  }
      
  accelerate(){
    return `Car is now travelling @ ${this._currentSpeed} mph.`;
  }
}

let input = document.getElementById('input1');
let myCar2 = new Vehicle("Green", 233, input.value, 90);

function whatsTheSpeed() {
  myCar2.setSpeed(input.value);
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =  myCar2.accelerate();
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <button onclick="whatsTheSpeed()">Speed</button>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Vehicle{
//Set up object
  constructor(color, direction, currentSpeed, topSpeed, engineStarted){
    this._color = color;
    this._direction = direction;
    this._currentSpeed = currentSpeed;
    this._topSpeed = topSpeed;
    this._engineStarted = true;
  }
      
  accelerate(){
     let input = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    return 'Car is now travelling @ ' + input + ' mph.';
  }
}


let myCar2 = new Vehicle("Green", 233, 20, 90);
function whatsTheSpeed() {
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML +=  myCar2.accelerate();
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <button onclick="whatsTheSpeed()">Speed</button>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```